# Websockets not working on AWS ElasticBeanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing a Spring Boot web application which uses WebSockets via the `spring-boot-starter-websocket` package. It works perfectly locally, but when I deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk everything except the WebSockets work. As far as I can tell, the requests never even reach the application, so it must be some sort of issue in the load balancer or one of the other layers in between.

In my browser console I can see that the browser tries to make a `wss://` connection to the server but it fails. It then tries to fallback to an `xhr` connection which also fails with a 403 status in this case. Then every few seconds it tries each of these options again and fails every time.

My Application Load Balancer is configured with a `https` listener on port 443 and `http-to-https` redirection is enabled. The server is running on port 5000. I have also added the WebSockets config file suggested by this resource: https://solitaired.com/websockets-elastic-beanstalk but it hasn't changed anything.

I would appreciate any advice about how to make this work. It is probably something pretty simple, but after a few hours of troubleshooting I can't find any solution that works for me. If there is any other information that would be helpful to know, I'd be happy to provide more details as needed.

Comment: That 403 sounds very much like something Spring /Tomcat specific. Websocket on EB works fine, given the more simple platforms like NodeJS.

Comment: I just tried. NodeJS Websocket start super easy without any special configuration. The NodeJS Runtime that EB provide is fronted by NGINX